# Ошибка на сайте Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php

Привет всем.

Пытаюсь установить один скрипт, но падает с ошибкой:

```
Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated.
```

Я так понимаю нужно поставить версию *php 5.3*, но как правильно изменить вот этот участок кода?

```
$template = ereg_replace("{([A-Z0-9_]+)}","",$template);

if (ereg("^(http://|ftp://|mailto:).*$", $back)) $back = "/_admin/";
```

Comment: Используйте функции preg_replace и preg_match. Основное отличие - внутри кавычек регулярку надо дополнительно заключать в косые. `preg_replace("/{([A-Z0-9_]+)}/"....)`

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Функции ereg_* являются устаревшими, вместо них следует использовать:

```
$template = preg_replace("/{([A-Z0-9_]+)}/","",$template);

if (preg_match('#^(http://|ftp://|mailto:)#', $back)) $back = "/_admin/";
```

Отличие этих функций в диалекте регулярных выражений (PCRE вместо расширенного POSIX). В вашем случае обе регулярки остаются без изменений. Но в новых функциях регулярку дополнительно надо заключать в какие либо символы, обычно в `/` или другой символ, если косые встречаются в самой регулряке и их лень экранировать.